# Spring - <constructor-arg> - java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError

Tags: spring, exception, constructor, javabeans

Hi I use EclipseEE and Java8_40. I start with the Spring Framework and have some problem. When I want use constructor in beans.xml the program create a Exception.

I have in CLASSPATH :
 
- commons-logging-1.2.jar
- commons-logging-1.2-javadoc.jar
and Spring *.jars
- spring-aop-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar
- spring-asm-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar
- spring-beans-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar
- spring-context-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar
- spring-aspects-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar
- spring-context-support-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar
- spring-core-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar
- spring-web-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar
- spring-webmvc-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar
- spring-expression-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar
SPRING BEAN

```
package beans;
public class SequenceGenerator {
    private String prefix;
    private String suffix;
    private int initial;
    private int counter;
    public SequenceGenerator() {}
    public SequenceGenerator(String prefix, String suffix, int initial) {
        this.prefix = prefix;
        this.suffix = suffix;
        this.initial = initial; }
    public void setPrefix(String prefix) {
        this.prefix = prefix;   }
    public void setSuffix(String suffix) {
        this.suffix = suffix;   }
    public void setInitial(int initial) {
        this.initial = initial; }
    public synchronized String getSequence() {
        StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
        buffer.append(prefix);
        buffer.append(initial + counter++);
        buffer.append(suffix);
        return buffer.toString();   }
}
```

CLIENT

```
package klient.program;
import org.springframework.context.*;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;
import beans.SequenceGenerator;
public class Program {
    @SuppressWarnings("resource")
    public static void main(String [] args){
        ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("beans.xml");
        SequenceGenerator generator = (SequenceGenerator) context.getBean("sequenceGenerator");
        System.out.println(generator.getSequence());
        System.out.println(generator.getSequence());
    }
}
```

BEANS.XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.1.xsd">
    <bean name="sequenceGenerator" class="beans.SequenceGenerator">
        <constructor-arg><value>30</value></constructor-arg>
        <constructor-arg><value>A</value></constructor-arg>
        <constructor-arg><value>100000</value></constructor-arg>
    </bean> 
</beans>
```

Exception :

`Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: class org.springframework.core.LocalVariableTableParameterNameDiscoverer$ParameterNameDiscoveringVisitor has interface org.springframework.asm.ClassVisitor as super class
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.core.LocalVariableTableParameterNameDiscoverer.inspectClass(LocalVariableTableParameterNameDiscoverer.java:114)
    at org.springframework.core.LocalVariableTableParameterNameDiscoverer.getParameterNames(LocalVariableTableParameterNameDiscoverer.java:87)
    at org.springframework.core.PrioritizedParameterNameDiscoverer.getParameterNames(PrioritizedParameterNameDiscoverer.java:65)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:182)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1131)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1034)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:504)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:755)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:757)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:480)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:139)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:83)
    at klient.program.Program.main(Program.java:8)`

Comment: Remove `spring-asm` jar .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need spring-asm-(version).jar.
This dependency was in spring-core earlier:

> Note however that we’ve eliminated the dedicated spring-asm jar in M2
>   in favor of including org.springframework.asm classes directly in
>   spring-core. Both of these upgrades are good news for JDK7 users
>   writing Spring components in dynamic JVM languages, as these new
>   versions of CGLIB and ASM properly handle the new invokedynamic
>   bytecode instruction introduced in JDK7.

http://spring.io/blog/2012/09/12/spring-framework-3-2-m2-released

How wrote here: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/commit/c16f18a5fd659f34d6290b5f2cffe54534b7592a this module full removed, instead use ASM 4